How to apply vector function on data.table
A function to sum 2 vectors
vsum = \(s) s[1] + s[2]

works well for data.frame
> vsum(expand.grid(1:2,2:3))
  Var1
1    3
2    4
3    4
4    5

but how to get the same result for data.table?
This is incorrect result:
> library(data.table)
> vsum(CJ(1:2,2:3))
      V1    V2
   <int> <int>
1:     2     5


Additional notes
I do not want the function with two variables.

If the vector are the element number 1 and 2 of a list (data.frame is a special type of lists) then the correct syntax is vsum = \(s){ s[[1]] + s[[2]] }

I like the function more vsum = \(s){ s[,1,drop=F] + s[,2,drop=F] } more, This works on both data frame and data.table. moreover gives result in data.frame and data.table rather than vector.

happy to accept the answer if you post.

Changing the function to
vsum = \(s){ s[,1,drop=F] + s[,2,drop=F] }

should give the desired result for both, data.frame and data.table.
Choosing columns with s[1] is a data.frame shortcut. With data.table it picks the row.

please one more request, this isnt working:vsum = \(s){ if(s[,1,drop =F] == s[,2,drop = F])  {s[,1, drop = F ]} else{s[,1, drop = F] + s[,2, drop = F] } }. I tried sing ifelse too.

Do you want to check equality of the whole vector or just value by value?

value by value.

In this case to make it work in both, data.frame and data.table, you might want to switch to vectors, e.g. vsum <- \(s) { data.frame(res = ifelse(s[,1] == s[,2], unlist(s[,1]), unlist(s[,1]) + unlist(s[,2]))) }

Thanks. I found this working well for data.table vsum = \(s){ ifelse(s[[1]] == s[[2]] ,  s[[1]] , s[[1]] + s[[2]] +s[[3]] )}. dataframe doesnt works but i dont care.

If you just want a vector result working with data.table try vsum <- \(s) { fifelse(s[,1] == s[,2], s[[1]], s[[1]] + s[[2]]) }. Also works with data.frames.

You can try list2DF as an intermediate processor
> vsum(list2DF(CJ(1:2, 2:3)))
  V1
1  3
2  4
3  4
4  5

